# Node Mongoose: Update many query with reference to current record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update one column of all rows collection by creating a concatnated string

My Schema has a property fileName and I would like construct a new property url.

Can I refernce the current row/record to build a query which would look something like this?

```
dbSchema.File.update({}, { $set: { url: '/view/images/'+ fileName}}, options, callback);
```

Obviously the above does not work because fileName is not in scope..

Whats the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do this manually and update each document in JavaScript and resave the document.

```
db.file.find().forEach(function(doc) {
   // make your needed updates
   db.file.update({_id:doc._id}, { $set : { url: 'newPath/' + filename }});
});
```

While you could do it from Mongoose, there's not much reason to if you have access to the console.

Otherwise, you'll need to do the exchange on the fly as you encounter unchanged documents, by looking for an indicator that the data hasn't been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was hoping that there would be some short way of doing it :)